# Accessing underlying type with LINQ during reflection

Tags: .net, linq, reflection

I've got my own little app for implementing solutions to the problems at http://projecteuler.net. I have a base class named `ProblemBase` which contains meta information about the problems, such as their id, name and description text, and a solver function. Every problem implementation then derives from this class.

The list of implementations is getting pretty large now, so instead of manually maintaining the solution container, I've walked into reflection land for the first time. The idea is to find all the types deriving from `ProblemBase` in my assembly, and instantiating them into the application's problem enumeration (`Problems` in the code below) so I can interact with them from my GUI. Here's my current implementation:

```
    private void FindProblemTypes()
    {
        var problemBaseType = typeof(ProblemBase);
        var problemTypes = (from t in Assembly.GetAssembly(problemBaseType).GetTypes()
                            where t != problemBaseType && problemBaseType.IsAssignableFrom(t)
                            select t).ToList();

        Problems = new ObservableCollection<ProblemBase>();
        foreach (var problemType in problemTypes)
        {
            Problems.Add((ProblemBase)Activator.CreateInstance(problemType));
        }

        Problems = new ObservableCollection<ProblemBase>(Problems.OrderBy(t => t.Id));
    }
```

It's working, but I'd like to clean it up a bit. Right now, I'm first creating a list of the derived types, then instatiating them into my collection, and then creating yet another collection to order the types by their id's. What I want to do is create my ObservableCollection directly from the first LINQ collection. I'd like to just add `orderby t.Id` in the LINQ statement, but since the type collection contains `System.Type` objects instead of `ProblemBase` objects, that property is unavailable, and I can't convert the variable to my base object inside the LINQ query. I'm assuming it's because the type information I'm requesting isn't known at compile time, but is there any other way to treat it like a `ProblemBase` object from within the query? Or do I have to stick with what I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var problemTypes = (from t in Assembly.GetAssembly(problemBaseType).GetTypes()
    where t != problemBaseType && problemBaseType.IsAssignableFrom(t)
    select (ProblemBase)Activator.CreateInstance(t)).ToList().OrderBy(t => t.Id);
```

Is that gonna work? You still need to AddRange to get it into your collection but that won't iterate through them so that's fine. I'm not the best at LINQ so you'll probably wanna test that out.

I don't think you'll ever be able to jam your "orderby id" into the original query as the items wont have been created by then.

Comment: That worked, I had forgotten I could do stuff directly from the Select statement. I created the ObservableCollection directly from the list returned from the query now. Thanks! :)